# Installation of the unity stock ticker lens failed

Tags: 12.04, unity, dependencies, lenses

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
unity-stock-ticker-lens : Depends: python-unity-singlet (>= 0.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and try the following:

> sudo apt-get -f install

The above will try to resolve the missing dependencies and broken packages

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu Software center search for `python-unity-singlet`. In front of package name there is the version, select `version 0.3 (quantal-backports)` and install.
Proceed with Ticker lens installation, it should install now.